# What is the correct terminology for a specific resource underneath a REST API?

Tags: rest, api-design

Say I provide a REST API at:

```
https://mycompany.com/api/v1
```

And GETting `https://mycompany.com/api/v1/user/<userID>` will return information about a user with that user ID (if it exists).

What would be the correct terminology for `/user/<userID>`?

I have considered the term 'endpoint' however it could be used to mean both the general REST API endpoint at `https://mycompany.com/api/v1` and the specific resource's endpoint at `https://mycompany.com/api/v1/user/<userID>`. I would like to be as specific as possible.

**Edit**: updated /users to /user as poster below notes.

Comment: The `users` part is the resource name, and the `<userID>` part is simply the resource identifier, or ID for short. BTW: Your resource name is wrong -- this seems to be a user with a user id, so the resource name should probably be `user`. I would expect a collection (identified through a noun) to have an index following it, not an ID.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Good point re: URL adjusted accordingly. My understanding is that everything identified by a URI is considered a resource, ie, in this case `https://mycompany.com/api/v1/user/abcdef` would be a resource. Do you have a reference that says otherwise?

Comment: My edits to my bad typing didn't get posted and now I can't edit my comment. I meant to say that the id is the resource's identifier, and I also meant to say that a collection is identified through a plural.

Comment: BTW: by definition you are right, everything identified by a resource identifier is a considered a resource.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question because I was also wondering about this exact same thing.
Then I found this article by ThoughtWorks: [REST API Design - Resource Modeling](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/rest-api-design-resource-modeling).

It uses the terminology "collection resource" vs "singleton resource", which I find helpful.

Example:

```
# collection resource:
/customers

# singleton resource
/customers/id-123
```

In contrast to commenters above, I would actively encourage you to use pluralized resource names everywhere to be consistent in your semantics, but I guess we can agree to disagree there.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint is `/users` in your case.

```
/users/id
```

is a `resource` and naming can changes according to your request method. (post/get/fetch/put etc). To sum up, it is resource of the endpoint. [this](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) resource may be useful for you

Comment: I'd already considered that option as mentioned in the question. I need a citation to be able to trust an answer.